# How to fade out/in all spans which have same id?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to fade out all span tags which have id="lt" and fade in tags which have id="en". I tried this code, but it only works for the first span.

```
$('#lt').fadeOut();
$('#en').fadeIn();
```

Comment: Id's should refer to one unique element, if you have several elements use a class.. so it'd be `$('.lt').fadeOut();`

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use IDs for multiple tags. Use class instead.
Then the solution would be like this:

```
$('.lt').fadeOut();
$('.en').fadeIn();
```